# How to take the first 3 random numbers from a 6 number loop?

Tags: java

So I'm supposed to make an **overloaded** program in **Java**. I have made my 2 methods on averaging the 6 numbers and the first 3 numbers. But I don't know how to store it into the parameters for the two methods. Here's my code so far:

```
    Random number = new Random();
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

    int num;
    int sum = 0;

    for(int counter = 1; counter <=6; counter++){
        num = 1 + number.nextInt(20);
        System.out.printf("Random number #%s: %s%n",counter,num);
        }

    }
    public static int avg (int a, int b, int c, int d, int e, int f){
        return ((a+b+c+d+e+f)/6);
    }
    public static int avg (int a, int b, int c){
        return((a+b+c)/3);
    }
```

Comment: try using an int array `new int[6]` and store the random numbers there. implement your avg methd to work with an array and as second parameter how many values from array to be considered for avg.

Comment: In your original code,  `return ((a+b+c+d+e+f)/6);` change 6 to 6.0 and change the `public static int` to `public static double`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I presume you aren't permitted to use arrays so just assign each to a variable.

```
        num1 = 1 + number.nextInt(20);
        num2 = 1 + number.nextInt(20);
        num3 = 1 + number.nextInt(20);
        // and so on for six numbers.
```

Then

```
       int avgerage = avg(num1, num2, num3, ...);
```

Note that since you are not using doubles your average won't have a decimal.

Otherwise, place the numbers in an array.

You can also do it like this:

```
      public int avg(int[] array) {
            int sum = 0;
            for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
              sum += array[i];
            }
            return sum/array.length;
       }
```

If permitted, I would recommend changing your values from `int` to `double`

Comment: So I did what you suggested (without the array because I'm not supposed to use them :/ ) but after i did that, my average still comes out like an integer, but with just .00 after it. It's not the correct average.

Comment: You should change all `int` to `double`.  Int values are always whole numbers with no decimal point.  Just changing the sum to double and the return type should do it.

Answer (score 4):

You create an array or a list of int and store the random number into the array/list. Then, you can call those two methods with the elements of the array/list

```
int[] array = new int[6];
for(int counter = 1; counter <=6; counter++){
    num = 1 + number.nextInt(20);
    array[counter-1] = num;
    System.out.printf("Random number #%s: %s%n",counter,num);
    }
}

int avg1 = avg(array[0],array[1],array[2]);
int avg2 = avg(array[0],array[1],array[2],array[3],array[4],array[5]);
```

Without using arrays, you create 6 int and drop the for loop

```
int i1 = 1 + number.nextInt(20);
int i2 = 1 + number.nextInt(20);
int i3 = 1 + number.nextInt(20);
int i4 = 1 + number.nextInt(20);
int i5 = 1 + number.nextInt(20);
int i6 = 1 + number.nextInt(20);
```

Then change the return type of your function to double

```
public static double avg (int a, int b, int c, int d, int e, int f){
     return ((a+b+c+d+e+f)/6.0); //change 6 to 6.0 so it doesn't do integer divide
}
public static double avg (int a, int b, int c){
     return((a+b+c)/3.0); //change 3 to 3.0 for same reason as above
}
```

```
double avg1 = avg(i1,i2,i3);
double avg2 = avg(i1,i2,i3,i4,i5,i6);
```

Comment: Thank you for the help on that. I'll probably need this on my next assignment. I can't use arrays tho :/

Comment: @ssethzz In that way create 6 separate integers, and change the return type to your avg method. I am editting the answer